# Автозапуск программы в Windows с правами администратора

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Необходимо добавить программу в автозапуск через cmd так чтобы она запускалась с правами администратора. 
Как мне это сделать? Думал если добавлю программу в автозапуск через реестр  или она сама себя добавит запустив ее от имени администратора то она будет запускаться при автозапуске с правами админа, но нет.
Буду благодарен за ответ!

Comment: как-то так: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/always-run-a-program-in-administrator-mode-in-windows-10/

Comment: Из HKCU\Soft\MS\Win\CV\Run запуск всегда выполняется с правами текущего пользователя. Добавляйте автозапуск через планировщик - там можно явно указать учётную запись для выполнения задания при входе. Или, как по ссылке у предыдущего оратора, запускайте линк, в свойствах которого указано выполнение от имени другой учётной записи.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант: через планировщик задач. Нужно создать задание с запуском процесса с правами суперпользователя, указать какой триггер для этого нужен: событие в журнале приложений, изменение файла в опред. каталоге и т.д. А в автозапуске нужно просто запустить триггер.